# Android : Imageview with fixed position on next activity

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am developing application where user capture's photo and moves to next activity with captured image. Now in next activity i have already given another image via XML which i am able to move and set anywhere over captured image now what i want is when i press OK button then this activity should move to next activity with captured image and also other image which i have set.

i have done with this but the problem is, i want to Fix the position of other image, example if i have set that image on captured images Nose then it should show on nose for Next activity. I don't have any idea about this. Can anyone tell me how to fix the absolute position of Image or any sample code that might help me.

Here you can see the photo, When i press OK button next activity looks something like this. http://share.pho.to/3wDYP

Comment: Advice: clarify your question. put some come with it or some images or links so that we can understand your problem. Also, put some paragraphs, it is really difficult to read.

Comment: Hi Dyna I am not able to post image because of reputation score..

Comment: you can upload them here: http://share.pho.to/ and share the link with us.

Comment: Thanks Dyna, I have added photo and link too.

Comment: What makes you think that this is not the right position? I think it is.

Comment: Besides moving nose and other parts into the next activity its better you replace or pass the whole edited image on the nextscreen and fix its position you capture the edited image and pass into next activity. @user2846106

Comment: Hey hasan, This application is developed in iOS and i need to implement same with android. So the screenshots which i have added is for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to merge these two images into one. Create a bitmap and add both images into one.

Here is an example [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736795/how-to-concate-combine-two-bitmaps-and-make-them-one-image-in-android) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151937/how-to-combine-multiple-images-into-a-single-image-in-android).

Also This is a very useful [Tutorial 1](http://androidattop.blogspot.in/2012/06/merge-multiple-images-into-one-image-in.html) and [Tutorial 2](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Combining_2_Images_in_Android_using_Canvas) for you.